# How to set size of a Gtk Image in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

How can I set the **width** and **height** of a **GTK Image** in **Python 3**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First create a  ***GdkPixbuf***  with the ***new_from_file_at_scale*** method which has the following syntax.

> **new_from_file_at_scale (filename, width, height, preserve_aspect_ratio)**

Create the widget ***Gtk.Image*** with the method ***new_from_pixbuf*** which receives a ***pixbuf*** as parameter.

**Simple Example:**

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(
        filename="1.jpg", 
        width=24, 
        height=24, 
        preserve_aspect_ratio=True)

image = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```